# Angular variable is not saving data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function which should return array of Articles, but after i get data they arent saving. Here is my console output.

```
GetAll() {
  //return this.http.get<Array<Article>>(this.cfg.SERVER);
  this.http.get(this.cfg.SERVER)
    .subscribe((data: Array<Article>) => {
      this.articles = data;
      console.log(1);
      console.log(this.articles);
    } 
  );
  console.log(2);
  console.log(this.articles);
  return this.articles;
}
```

[ConsoleView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18X5c.jpg)

Comment: The get call is async. The GetAll method returns bevor the answer is sent to the client.

Comment: You had it right with the commented code. Return the `Observable` provided by the http call. As written, the `GetAll()` method will always return null because you return before the callback in `subscribe` executes.

Comment: @TheHeadRush how to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it right with the commented code. Return the Observable provided by the http call. As written, the GetAll() method will always return null because you return before the callback in subscribe executes.

Try this:

```
GetAll(): Observable<Array<Article>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Article>>(this.cfg.SERVER);
}
```

If the variable receiving the output of this method has a declared type, you will need to change its type to `Observable<Array<Article>>`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try as below way.

```
for(var i=0;i<this.articles.length;i++)
{
 console.log("id:"+this.articles[i].id+"Title:"+this.articles[i].title");
}
```